# Facebook API for Mac Application

Tags: facebook, macos, cocoa, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm developing a Mac application to share the files (video, images) to Facebook using the Facebook API.

In the Facebook SDKs & Tools, I can find only iOS SDK (iPhone & iPad), but not the one specific for Mac application. Does it mean we've to use the iOS SDK for the Mac apps too? If so how can I make use of iOS SDK in Mac application? Actually I tried to use iOS, but it was not successful, and not only that even I had to re-install frameworks which I was using for some other purposes too. The error was related to NSString.

Can anyone advise me in integrating the Facebook API for my Mac application?

Answer (score 2):

There is one sample code written by someone.I've seen on internet. Here you go

http://developer.casgrain.com/?p=107